# URL Core Rewrite - more than one rewrite for one product

Tags: magento-1.9, products, url-rewrite

I would like to add more rewrites for a specific product.

For example I have
Product a - url: urlpath/product-original-path.html

I would like three rewerites

1. urlpath/product-old-path1.html
2. urlpath/product-old-path2.html
3. urlpath/product-old-path3.html

to http://website.com/product-original-path.html

I guess it isn't possible using core_url_rewrite. Any solutions? Extensions to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2):

In you backend got to `Catalog > URL Rewrite management` and add a new rule.
Now for the following steps

1. Choose product
2. Pick your product
3. Either pick a category or skip
4. Next in the form choose the store it applies to
5. Fill out the `request path` which should be the URL you want to redirect

And that should be it

Comment: When I add first rewrite it works but I want to add another and then I get "ID Path for Specified Store already exists."

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

Instead of creating a *Product* URL Rewrite, create a **Custom** URL Rewrite:

[image: create custom rewrite]

Repeat for the second and third paths, choosing a different value for `ID Path` each time.

## Longer Explanation

Magento sets a unique constraint in the `core_url_rewrite` table for the combination of `store_id` and `id_path`. It relies on this to look up the correct URL for a particular entity, such as a product or category.

Here is an extract from Magento's core which loads the URL 
 based on the `store_id` and `id_path`:

```php
// app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Url.php
protected function _getRequestPath($product, $categoryId)
{   
    $idPath = sprintf('product/%d', $product->getEntityId());
    if ($categoryId) {
        $idPath = sprintf('%s/%d', $idPath, $categoryId);
    }   
    $rewrite = $this->getUrlRewrite();
    $rewrite->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
        ->loadByIdPath($idPath);
    if ($rewrite->getId()) {
        return $rewrite->getRequestPath();
    }   

    return false;
}
```

When you create a new URL Rewrite Rule for a product, the `id_path` is automatically set to `product/<product_id>`. However, Magento has a way of working around this limitation when it creates multiple redirects for the same product. See this method from the core:

```php
// app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php
protected function _saveRewriteHistory($rewriteData, $rewrite)
{   
    if ($rewrite instanceof Varien_Object && $rewrite->getId()) {
        $rewriteData['target_path'] = $rewriteData['request_path'];
        $rewriteData['request_path'] = $rewrite->getRequestPath();
        $rewriteData['id_path'] = $this->generateUniqueIdPath();
        $rewriteData['is_system'] = 0;
        $rewriteData['options'] = 'RP'; // Redirect = Permanent
        $this->getResource()->saveRewriteHistory($rewriteData);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

The `generateUniqueIdPath` method simply generates a value based on the current time:

```php
public function generateUniqueIdPath()
{   
    return str_replace('0.', '', str_replace(' ', '_', microtime()));
}
```

So if you want to create URL Rewrites with `id_path` values that follow this logic, simply run this method in a stand-alone script. It will give you values that look like this: `68704200_1501155122`.